# Previously owned car is now abandoned

Tags: arizona, car, name-title, car-title, vehicle-registration

I sold a car in January of 2022. The car was registered to the new owner legally at the DMV. Fast forward to April of 2023 I get a letter in the mail saying I’m the owner per their record and the car has been abandoned. I contacted the buyer and they never renewed their registration. The car has been sitting as they blew up the engine. The form states I can either accept responsibility for the ticket or I could fight it. Could I legally go get the car ?

Comment: "The car was registered to the new owner legally at the DMV."  How do you know that?

Comment: The legal answer is "no", as you probably know. (Maybe you could get away with it, but that does not make it legal.) The practical answer is to email the current owner and ask if you can get the car back for free (and you will deal with the fine and repairs), assuming that’s what you want.

Comment: Do you have any paper trail which proves the sale?